# Sort DataRow[] using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

DataRow[] drTest contains `System.Data.DataRow`, say, contains 10 `DataRow`'s. Inside of each DataRow, I have an ItemArray that contains `Name` and `Count`.
Now I want to sort the DataRow[] drTest in descending order based on the ItemArray second record count.

Example:

```
DataRow[] drTest contains 

At [0] Index - ItemArray[0] - "A"
             - ItemArray[1] - 5

At [1] Index - ItemArray[0] - "B"
             - ItemArray[1] - 7
```

I want to order drTest in descending order, so that drTest[1] should come up.

Answer (score 7):

A great way of playing with LINQ is using [LINQPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad). Here's a quick sample I wrote and tested to answer your question:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

table.Rows.Add("A", 5);
table.Rows.Add("B", 7);
table.Rows.Add("C", 1);
table.Rows.Add("D", 8);
table.Rows.Add("E", 9);
table.Rows.Add("F", 6);
table.Rows.Add("G", 3);
table.Rows.Add("H", 2);
table.Rows.Add("I", 4);

var sorted = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .OrderByDescending(row => row[1]);

// If you are using LINQPad you can test this using the following line:
sorted.Dump();
```

Answer (score 3):

This should give you what you are looking for:

```
var result = drTest.OrderByDescending(dr => dr[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following LINQ query to sort your item array in descending order.

```
var result = drTest.OrderByDescending(itemArray => itemArray [1]);
```

or

```
var result = from row in drtest 
             orderby row[1] descending 
             select row;
```

For more information, you can go through *[LINQ - Ordering Operators](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Ordering-Operators-050af19e)*.