# Sorting a List of type DataRow in C# based on the int values in the Data Column

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable

I want to order my `List<DataRow>`based on a particular column of int values. 
For example if each DataRow in my list has two columns like `|ID|NAME|` I want my list to contain the DataRows with an ascending order of IDs.

I know that you can use string compare to sort out the list of DataRows

```
list.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a["NAME"].ToString(), b["NAME"].ToString()));
```

But in my case I need to be sorting out the integer values in the columns of the DataRows in an ascending order

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890325/sort-datarow-using-linq

Comment: I want to sort my list itself and not the DataTable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using order by Considering your list Column ID only has numbers

```
list.OrderBy(row => row.Field<int>("ID"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using the CompareTo Method,

```
list.Sort((a, b) => int.Parse(a["ID"].ToString()).CompareTo(int.Parse(b["ID"].ToString())));
```